# How to add z-index via object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible add `z-index` via [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method thought object:

```
jQuery('<div/>').css({
        z-index: 1000, 
        opacity: 0.7, 
        width: jQuery(window).width(), 
        height: jQuery(document).height(), 
        top:0, 
        left:0, 
        position: 'absolute'}).appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("<div>").css({
    zIndex: 123
}).appendTo("body");
```

or

```
$("<div>").css({
    "z-index": 123
}).appendTo("body");
```

---

[***`.css()`*** doc](http://api.jquery.com/css/#entry-longdesc-1):

> ... Also, jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns the correct value for both **`.css({'background-color': ...})`** and **`.css({backgroundColor: ...})`**.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('div').css('z-index',1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

yes but you have to use apostrophes/quotation `'z-index`  marks:

```
jQuery('<div/>').css({
    "z-index": 1000, 
    opacity: 0.7, 
    width: jQuery(window).width(), 
    height: jQuery(document).height(), 
    top:0, 
    left:0, 
    position: 'absolute'}).appendTo('body');
```